# How can perform a database query without id in the url?

Tags: url, web

I saw link like: http://www.quora.com/Web-Design. And that link lists all the questions in the Web Design topic.

I am just curious how they perform database query. I dont think they use Web-Design as a key to fetch data. Cause' I often see link similar like: http://www.myweb.com/Web-Design-1234, where 1234 is the topic id.

DO you have any idea how they do it? or they just use the topic name (Web-Design) as a key to retrieve data?

Comment: I think they just use topic name as a unique key for fetching data. The topic name could be a unique key of an individual topic or even a topic group which contains other topics.

Comment: at first, I think so too. But when I view a question, the link is http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-most-effective-way-to-read-a-textbook. and with that link, I dont think they use the title of the question as a key to fetch the question content.

Comment: the url does not have to be same as question title, there might something like **question name** underlying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about it,since it is the internal structure of the site, But these are some ideas which can achieve this AFAIK
if you see the link you could understand that they using

http://www.quora.com/Typography/What-are-some-free-tools-to-lay-out-text-beautifully

```
                    ^                ^
              first key tag      second key tag
```

and the Question's name as key.